# idempotent functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $X$ be a set of three elements, say $X=\{1,2,3\}$. I'm searching functions $f:X\longrightarrow X$ such that $f\circ f=f$. In particular, i'm interested in number of such functions $f$, how many are there? Can i generalize for $n$ in place of 3?

Comment: There are only $27$ such functions. You could enumerate them, and check which ones work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each such $f$ we have the nonempty set $f(X)\subseteq X$. By the condition, $f|{f(X)}$ is the identity, whereas for $x\notin f(X)$, the value of $f(x)\in f(X)$ does not matter.

Thus for any $k$ with $1\le k\le n=|X|$, we can select a subset $S\subseteq X$ of size $k$ and then for each $x\notin S$ choose an element of $S$ as $f(x)$ (whereas $f(x)=x$ for $x\in S$).
Therefore we find
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}k^{n-k}$$
such functions.

Se allso OEIS sequence [A000248](http://oeis.org/A000248).