# What are some examples of Idempotent functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

I'd just like to know for my own experimentation a list of known functions in algebra that satisfy $$ f(f(x))=f(x), $$ like how there's a list of known involution functions on wikipedia. But somehow, I can't find a single example anywhere on the internet of even one idempotent function.

Comment: Note that if $f$ is idempotent and differentiable, then $f'(f(x)) \cdot f'(x)=f'(x)\,$ so $f'(x)=0$ on its domain, or $f'(y)=1$ on its range, or some combination thereof. That severely limits the potentially candidate functions, and explains some of the posted examples.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but $$f(x)=e^{ln(x^n)^{1/n}}$$ is an idemptotent function because $$ e^{ln(e^{ln(x^n)^{1/n}}^n)^{1/n}}=e^{ln(x^n)^{1/n}} $$ correct? This would be the kind of function I'm looking for. if I say n=2, you can see more clearly that http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(ln(e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))

Comment: The [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) didn't come out right in your previous comment, so I am not sure what function you meant to write. The one in the WA link doesn't look to be idempotent.

Comment: It comes out right on my end. Here, I have the original function, e^(ln(x^2)^(1/2)) http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) and now, look what happens when I composite that function into itself http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(ln(e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) I get the original function. This is the kind of function I'm looking for.

Comment: According to the same WA [f(x) - f(f(x))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))+-+e%5E(ln(+(e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)))%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))) doesn't look to be $0$ for that function.

Comment: That's weird because I just used that to prove it http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))-e%5E(ln(e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))

Comment: I think there was an issue with the brackets. Try using only curved brackets. I'm absolutely sure there are other functions that do this, I've coincidentally come across them before much like involutions.

Comment: There were *no* other brackets than curved ones in my WA link. If you mean some different function which WA says it satisfies $f(x)-f(f(x))=0$ then please post the link.

Comment: No right here this is what I was working with the whole time, f(x)-f(f(x))=0 http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))-e%5E(ln(e%5E(ln(x%5E2)%5E(1%2F2))%5E2)%5E(1%2F2)) I don't know why you're having such difficulty with this, it works perfectly for me.

Comment: You are missing parentheses, look again and compare vs the link I posted

Comment: I really don't know why we're not on the same page. It's certainly possible it's wrong, but every time I type it in...it seems to work for me. I guess I'll just have to leave it for now and see if there's anything else, I haven't tried to prove it yet anyway so nothing to be worried about, but regardless you see the kinds of functions I'm looking for right? Would be a shame if all we had were those basic abs and sign functions.

Comment: Let your $f(x)=e^{\sqrt{\ln(x^2)}}\,$, then $f(e)=e^{\sqrt{2}}\simeq 4.11\,$, $f(e^{\sqrt{2}})=e^{2^{3/4}} \simeq 5.38\,$, so $f(f(e)) \ne f(e)\,$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is continuous and idempotent then $I=f(\mathbb R)$ is a closed interval and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in I$.
2. If $f$ is also differentiable and nonconstant, then $I=\mathbb R$, i.e., $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

**Proof of 1.**: If $f$ is continuous and idempotent, then $I=f(\mathbb R)$ is an interval by continuity alone along with the IVT. If $A=\{x\in \mathbb R: f(x)=x\}$, then $A$ is a closed set by continuity, $A\subseteq I$ because each $x\in A$ equals $f(x)\in I$, and $I\subseteq A$ by idempotency.  Thus $I=A$, confirming that $I$ is a *closed* interval on which $f$ is the identity function.

**Proof of 2.**: Suppose that $f$ is continuous and idempotent, but not constant and not the identity function.  Then $I$ is not $\mathbb R$, not a singleton, so by 1. $I$ is a nontrivial closed interval that is either bounded above or below (or both).  Suppose $I$ is bounded above, and let $b=\sup(I)=\max(I)$, the last equality holding by closedness of $I$.  Because $I$ is a nontrivial interval, $I$ contains $(a,b]$ for some $a<b$.  It follows that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=b$, because $\lim\limits_{h\to 0-}\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}=1$, but for all $h>0$, $\dfrac{f(b+h)-f(b)}{h}\leq 0$.   If $f$ is bounded below a similar argument applies to show that $f$ is not differentiable at $\inf(I)=\min(I)$. By contraposition, this confirms that if $f$ is idempotent, differentiable and nonconstant, then $I=\mathbb R$, i.e., $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

---

In the case where $f$ is continuous and not constant or the identity function, the graph of $f$ consists of a closed line segment or ray on the line $y=x$, having the form $\{(x,x):x\in f(\mathbb R)\}$, then extends continuously in a way that is arbitrary as long as the $y$ values stay in $I=f(\mathbb R)=f(I)$.  This is a special case of [Jair Taylor's more general description](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2255848/), where $S$ must be a interval and the pieced together map must be continuous.

For a given bounded interval $[a,b]$, $a<b$, a formula for a continuous idempotent function $f$ having $[a,b]=f(\mathbb R)$ is 
$$f(x)=\frac{b-a}{\pi}\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi(x-\frac12(a+b))}{b-a}\right)\right)+\frac{a+b}{2},$$

a triangle wave function obtained by dilating and shifting the example $\arcsin(\sin(x))$ given in [Jair Taylor's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2255848/).  To get arbitrary closed rays instead, you can shift and reflect $y=|x|$ to get $y=\pm|x-h|+h$.

Comment: So in other words, it's double proven that the only real idempotent functions are the ones with a derivative of 1?

Comment: @RayOfHope: I wouldn't use those words, but if by "real" you mean differentiable, nonconstant, and defined on all of $\mathbb R$, this does provide proof of something more specific than that the derivative is $1$, namely that the function is the identity function.  Are you are referring to how it complements [dxiv's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2255890/)? I agree they are related.  dxiv has commented pointing out how you can have differentiable examples on disconnected domains that are sometimes the identity, other times constant.

Answer (score 5):

A *[projection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(mathematics))* is a linear map satisfying $P^2=P$. These are always idempotent, by definition.

Comment: I mean like an actual algebraic function like in functional analysis, not linear algebra, like something involving y=x^2 or y=gamma(x) or something like that, you know? I ran across operators like that in linear algebra and things from computer science, but that's really not what I'm looking for.

Comment: How about the [sign function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)?

Comment: @RayOfHope: Whatever you mean by "functional analysis" doesn't appear to be what the term usually means in mathematics.  Linear idempotent maps, and most of linear algebra, are important in functional analysis.   You can write formulas for linear idempotent maps. E.g., $f:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $f(x,y) = (\frac12(x+y),\frac12(x+y))$ is an example.  Do you mean you only want functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 3):

Here are several:

1. $f(x)=x$
2. $f(x)=\vert x\vert$
3. $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$
4. $f(x)=\lceil x\rceil$

Comment: and then a*arcsin(sin(...))

Answer (score 3):

Any idempotent function $P: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ can be constructed by

1) Choosing your favorite set $S$.

2) Find a mapping $P:\mathbb{R} \backslash S$ into $S$.

3) Expand the domain of $P$ by letting let $P(x) = x$ for $x \in S$.

This is, for example, how $P(x) = |x|$ works.  It just maps the negative part of the real line onto the positive part, and acts as the identity on the positive part.

But if you want this to be a function with a nice formula it's not quite as obvious.  One way is to use any non one-to-one function that $f(x)$ that has a right inverse $g(x)$, so that $f(g(x)) = x$.  Then if $P(x) = g(f(x))$ then $P\circ P = g \circ f \circ g \circ f = g \circ f = P$.

Intuitively, $g$ works by mapping an input $y$ to an $x$ in a select domain $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ so that $f(x) = y$.  Then on this particular set $A$, we have $g(f(x)) = g(y) = x$.

For example, think about $P(x) = \arcsin(\sin(x))$ where $arcsin$ is the usual branch taking $x$ into $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$.

Note that this only really works for certain inverse functions we decided are okay to write in formulas, like $\sqrt{x}$ or $\arcsin(x)$.  Most of these examples are going to be a little bit artificial, because if $P$ is the identity on on a set $S$ that contains an interval than it 'really ought' to be the identity everywhere.  That is, it must be the identity if it is analytic.

Comment: A general formula for an idempotent triangle wave map is $$f(x)=a\arcsin\left(\sin\left(\frac{x-h}{a}\right)\right)+h.$$ "...if it is analytic." Isn't it even if it is differentiable and nonconstant?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Hmm, I think you're right but the proof's not immediately obvious to me.

Comment: I posted an answer with proof.

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the comment:

> Note that if $f$ is idempotent and differentiable, then $f′(f(x))⋅f′(x)=f′(x)$ so $f′(x)=0$ on its domain, or $f′(y)=1$ on its range, or some combination thereof.

Take any partition of the reals $\mathbb{R} = \bigcup R_k\,$, and for each $R_k$ define a function $f_k : R_k \to R_k$ which is either linear $f_k(x)=x$ or constant $f_k(x)=c_k \in R_k$. Then "combine" all those functions into one function $f(x) = f_k(x) \;\;\text{iff}\;\; x \in R_k\,$, and that function $f(x)$ is idempotent. This construction covers several of the posted functions, for example $R_k = [k, k+1)$ and $f_k(x) = k$ gives $f(x)= \lfloor x \rfloor$.

For a more offbeat (and nowhere continuous) idempotent function, consider for example:

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
0 &\quad\quad \text{if}\; x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q} \\
p\,q &\quad\quad \text{if}\; x =p/q \in \mathbb{Q} \;\;\text{with}\;  p, q \in \mathbb{Z}\;\;\text{and}\;\; \gcd(p,q)=1 
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: "or some combination thereof" No combinations occur; if $f$ is idempotent and differentiable, then $f(x)=x$ for all $x$ or $f$ is constant.  Proof is posted in my answer, which I am mentioning to back up my claim, not intending to self-promote.

Comment: @JonasMeyer That's correct if the domain of $f$ is an interval or the whole $\mathbb{R}\,$. "*Combinations thereof*" are still possible if the domain is, for example, the union of two intervals with disjoint closures.

Comment: Thanks, good point. Would the closures need to be disjoint, or just the closure of each disjoint from the others?  I.e., wouldn't disjoint open intervals allow for arbitrary combinations?

Comment: @JonasMeyer Right. I was just (overly) careful to avoid misunderstandings like $[0,1) \cup [1,2)\,$.

Answer (score 0):

A very late answer, but I just discovered this question and I am a bit surprised by the answers, since the OP did not give any specification on the domain of $f$. There is actually no need of topology and the answer is quite trivial:

Let $f:X \to X$ be a function. Then $f$ is idempotent if and only if its restriction to its range is the identity.

This is implicitly Jair Taylor's answer, but this is also the argument used in this [Hagen von Eitzen's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/319361), over ten years ago.

To answer your question as stated in the title, here is the list of the four functions from $\{1,2\}$ to itself. The idempotents are $I$, $b$ and $c$.
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
&1 &2 \\
\hline
I&1 &2 \\
a&2 &1 \\
b&1 &1 \\
c&2 &2 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Let me add a few comments to make this answer more consistent.
[Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem) states that every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of a symmetric group, but this theorem easily generalises to monoids: any monoid is a [transformation monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_semigroup) on its underlying set. Thus this characterisation of idempotent transformations gives a simple way to find the idempotents of any semigroup (and it is useful for computational purpose). See [1, Section 2.7] for more information on idempotents of a transformation semigroup.

Halfway between groups and semigroups, [Wagner–Preston's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_semigroup#Homomorphisms_and_representations_of_inverse_semigroups) states that any inverse semigroup can be embedded in a symmetric inverse semigroup. The set of all partial bijections (i.e. one-to-one partial functions) on a set $X$ forms an inverse monoid ${\cal I}_X$, called the [symmetric inverse semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_inverse_semigroup). The idempotents of ${\cal I}_X$ are exactly the partial identities. It follows that they form an idempotent and commutative monoid isomorphic to the monoid $({\cal P}(X), \cap)$.

[1] O. Ganyushkin and V. Mazorchuk, *Classical finite transformation semigroups, An introduction*. Algebra and Applications, 9. Springer-Verlag London, Ltd., London, (2009). xii+314 pp. ISBN: 978-1-84800-280-7