# Does an idempotent function has to be 1-Lipschitz?

Tags: lipschitz-functions, idempotents

A function $f$ satisfying $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$ is called an Idempotent function. I want to know if it has to be a Lipschitz function. **Actually, I am training a neural network which has to be idempotent. Now I need to know whether imposing Lipschitz regularization can improve my results.**

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @LSK21 I have gone through some literature and tried to prove this. But at this point, I'm not even sure whether the statement is true

Comment: An idempotent function does not even need to be continuous, why should it have to be Lipschitz? Consider the floor function, it is not continuous, but clearly idempotent

Comment: @LSK21 Thanks for your insight. Thats a nice counter example. Is there a way to prove that its Lipschitz locally with some constraints maybe?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2256339/1024488